# Cycle Plugin: Turn the pager thumbnail into a slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, cycle

I'm trying to work on a cycle image gallery and so far everything is working perfectly but I wanted to know if it was possible Turn the pager thumbnail into a slider.

I try this plugin [simplyscroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/vertical.html) and unfortunately it's not working. I don't know why maybe because there is a conflict between two plugin.

I just want to turn the thumb like image below:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your HTML and js

Comment: you can visit this site for the demo http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html

Comment: Instead of actual images you want to use image thumbnail for slider, and that should appear as the image you given in the question. Right?

Comment: can someone explain for the downvote!!! if you have no idea what to do!!! just simple leave this page....

Comment: @jhunlio when you get downvoted either the question is not really clear and you didn't provide enough background to let us answer your question. You want the pager to be scrollable left and right, or you want a set of pictures sitting in the same container which transitions between them? Do you have some Fiddle/Codepens to share to let us see what have you done so far? Those simple things helps your question to receive more attention and get answered rather than sticking a bounty on top of it and sitting down waiting for a reply. Review your question and you shall get the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I have found that It is better to change the plugin you used, so I found that this plugin can handle it easy.

https://adgallery.codeplex.com/

ad gallery has already sliding thumbnail in the bottom part of the image and easy to used.

Answer (score 0):

there is a slider plug-in on github 
[link to GitHub Page](https://github.com/priteshgupta/vivid-photo) 
I found this similar to your slider 
and you can see the live demo of there slider at priteshgupta.com/demos/templates/vivid-photo/
the thumbnails slide on Mousemove event

then i modified this slightly by adding my custom function for auto sliding the thumbnail

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i=i+30) {
     $thumbScroller_container.animate({left:-i}, $scrollEasing,$scrollEasingType); 
   }
```

ORIGINALLy  IT WAS

```
$thumbScroller.mousemove(function(e){
        if($thumbScroller_container.width()>sliderWidth){
            var mouseCoords=(e.pageX - $placement[1]);
            var mousePercentX=mouseCoords/sliderWidth;
            var destX=-((((totalContent+($tsMargin*2))-(sliderWidth))-sliderWidth)*(mousePercentX));
            var thePosA=mouseCoords-destX;
            var thePosB=destX-mouseCoords;
            if(mouseCoords>destX){
                $thumbScroller_container.stop().animate({left: -thePosA}, $scrollEasing,$scrollEasingType); //with easing
            } else if(mouseCoords<destX){
                $thumbScroller_container.stop().animate({left: thePosB}, $scrollEasing,$scrollEasingType); //with easing
            } else {
                $thumbScroller_container.stop();  
            }
        }
});
```

now it will work as you stated in query
this is changed preview
[link to demo](http://txtwheel.com/more/vivid-photo-master/index.html)
js file which i edited 
 [Gallery page i edited](http://txtwheel.com/more/vivid-photo-master/scripts/gallery.js) 
if you want to access any event like click in jquery then you can use trigger for that